# Регулярное выражение на проверку textarea (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть текстовое поле, в котором может быть что угодно. То есть ограничения на символы отсутствует. Нужно исключить возможность отправки только пробелов (или пробельных символов), только переносов строк или комбинацию только пробелов и только переносов и не должно быть пустым

Comment: Не понял, может быть что угодно или только `\s\n`? Приведите примеры подходящих и не подходящих тестов

Comment: @dIm0n наверно не очень понятно расписал. В поле может быть что угодно. Но нужно исключить возможность отправить только пробелы, только переносы или комбинацию пробелов и переносов

Comment: Именно пробелов или любых пробельных символов (табов, например)? Добавьте это в вопрос

Comment: @dIm0n изменил вопрос

Comment: А пустым поле может быть?

Comment: Пустым тоже быть не может. Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
^(?:(?![\s\n]+$)[\s\S])+$
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5aiq1

Comment: Та за шо минус?

Answer (score 0):

Содержит хотя бы 1 не-пробельный символ: `value.match(/\S/)`

Comment: С такой регуляркой надо проверять, что есть хотя бы 1 матч, а не валидирировать поле (подходит/не подходит). Напишите JavaScript функцию, с помощью которой это можно сделать тогда

Comment: Если 1 матч есть, значит подходит.